# Spring ControllerAdvice - Fail to override handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported() in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, api, spring-mvc, microservices, spring-restcontroller

Here's a few facts for the situation that I'm currently facing

1. I have recently built a `RestControllerAdvice` with various`ExceptionHandler` as a global exception handler for my Spring RestController.
2. As I would like to return my customized response json for handling the pre-defined HTTP error as specified in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, my `RestControllerAdvice` class inherits the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and methods like `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported()`, `handleHttpMessageNotReadable()` are overriden.
3. I have successfully overridden `handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported()` and `handleHttpMessageNotReadable()` but when it comes to `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported()`, I fail to do so.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations=RestController.class)
public class TestRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        BaseResponseJson response = new BaseResponseJson();
        response.setRespCode(BaseResponseJson.JSON_RESP_CODE_ERROR);
        response.setRespMsg("Request Method Not Supported");
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, response, headers, status, request);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        BaseResponseJson response = new BaseResponseJson();
        response.setRespCode(BaseResponseJson.JSON_RESP_CODE_ERROR);
        response.setRespMsg("Message Not Readable");
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, response, headers, status, request);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        BaseResponseJson response = new BaseResponseJson();
        response.setRespCode(BaseResponseJson.JSON_RESP_CODE_ERROR);
        response.setRespMsg("Media Type Not Supported");
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, response, headers, status, request);
    }
}
```

The log for `handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported()` is shown as follow:

```
[2019-06-05T17:49:50.368+0800][XNIO-74 task-7][WARN ][o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

The log for `handleHttpMessageNotReadable()` is shown as follow:

```
[2019-06-05T17:50:21.915+0800][XNIO-74 task-8][WARN ][o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved exception caused by Handler execution
```

As you can see, the successful code is handled by `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` while the malfunction code is handled by `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`.

I am wondering what is the underlying reason and I will appreciate if someone can recommend any available solution. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, the request sucessfully returns HTTP405, but I cant get the BaseResponseJson that im trying to override

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the **jackycflau** answer, we can summarise as 2 questions.

> **Q1. Why removing `annotations=RestController.class` will works for HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException**
>
> **Q2. Why only `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` is not caught?**

To answer these 2 questions, we need to take a look to code on how spring handle exceptions. The following source code are based on spring 4.3.5.

During spring `DispatcherServlet` processing the request, when error occur, `HandlerExceptionResolver` will try to resolve the exception. In the given case, the exception is delegated to `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`. The method to determine which method to resolve the exception is (`getExceptionHandlerMethod` in `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java` line 417)

```
/**
 * Find an {@code @ExceptionHandler} method for the given exception. The default
 * implementation searches methods in the class hierarchy of the controller first
 * and if not found, it continues searching for additional {@code @ExceptionHandler}
 * methods assuming some {@linkplain ControllerAdvice @ControllerAdvice}
 * Spring-managed beans were detected.
 * @param handlerMethod the method where the exception was raised (may be {@code null})
 * @param exception the raised exception
 * @return a method to handle the exception, or {@code null}
 */
protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handlerMethod, Exception exception) {
    Class<?> handlerType = (handlerMethod != null ? handlerMethod.getBeanType() : null);

    if (handlerMethod != null) {
        ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver resolver = this.exceptionHandlerCache.get(handlerType);
        if (resolver == null) {
            resolver = new ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver(handlerType);
            this.exceptionHandlerCache.put(handlerType, resolver);
        }
        Method method = resolver.resolveMethod(exception);
        if (method != null) {
            return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(handlerMethod.getBean(), method);
        }
    }

    for (Entry<ControllerAdviceBean, ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver> entry : this.exceptionHandlerAdviceCache.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().isApplicableToBeanType(handlerType)) {
            ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver resolver = entry.getValue();
            Method method = resolver.resolveMethod(exception);
            if (method != null) {
                return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(entry.getKey().resolveBean(), method);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Since we are using `@RestControllerAdvice`, we only need to focus in the for loop, which determine which `ControllerAdviceBean` to use. We can see that the method `isApplicableToBeanType` will determine if the `ControllerAdviceBean` is applicable, and the related code are (`ControllerAdviceBean.java` line 149)

```
/**
 * Check whether the given bean type should be assisted by this
 * {@code @ControllerAdvice} instance.
 * @param beanType the type of the bean to check
 * @see org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice
 * @since 4.0
 */
public boolean isApplicableToBeanType(Class<?> beanType) {
    if (!hasSelectors()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (beanType != null) {
        for (String basePackage : this.basePackages) {
            if (beanType.getName().startsWith(basePackage)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (Class<?> clazz : this.assignableTypes) {
            if (ClassUtils.isAssignable(clazz, beanType)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass : this.annotations) {
            if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanType, annotationClass) != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasSelectors() {
    return (!this.basePackages.isEmpty() || !this.assignableTypes.isEmpty() || !this.annotations.isEmpty());
}
```

By reading the code, we can explain what is happening:

### Answer for Q1

When `annotations=RestController.class` is removed, `hasSelectors` will return false, and hence `isApplicableToBeanType` will return true. So `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` will be handled by `TestRestExceptionHandler` in this case.

### Answer for Q2

For `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`, `DispatcherSerlvet` can not find controller method to handle request. Hence `handlerMethod` passed to `getExceptionHandlerMethod` is `null`, then `beanType` passed to `isApplicableToBeanType` is also null and false is returned.

On the other hand, `DispatcherSerlvet` can find controller method for `HttpMessageNotReadableException` or `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`. So the rest controller handler method will be passed to `getExceptionHandlerMethod` and `isApplicableToBeanType` will return true.

Comment: thanks for help! nice answer. Would you mind to explain more on how to determine when would the `handlerMethod` be null?

Comment: If the exception is thrown before/during finding the `handlerMethod`,  it will be passed as null, otherwise it will not be null. You may take a look for the case of `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` in `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping` line 192.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the culprit of the issue, which is regarding the `@RestControllerAdvice` annotation.

Orginally, I have annotated the class with `@RestControllerAdvice(annotations=RestController.class)`.

After I remove the `annotations` key-value pair (i.e. just annotate the class with `@RestControllerAdvice`), `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` is now successfully caught.

This is the solution that I can only be able to share. I don't understand the underlying reason and such behavior seems quite weird to me... Probably because the `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` is not under the control by `@RestController`??? (just a wild guess). I will be happy if someone can give a full explanation on such behavior.